# Exact whole string search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find exact match row for the given word not like wise row please help me out for searching exact word match row i am using a data base please find the database screen shot:

[image]

I am using the following query for getting only "block type row but i am getting the "no block" row also, Please help me for getting the solution.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "query_string": {
                    "default_field": "block",
                    "query": "block",
                    "default_operator": "AND"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "block.keyword",
            "query": "Block"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even better, transform your `block` field before syncing into a boolean of `has_block`:true/false and then use `{term: { has_block:true } }`